# Enable audio autoplay in Chrome for web apps installed on the user's Android desktop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, autoplay, web-audio-api

I have developed a **progressive web app** that can be run in kiosk mode / standalone from the user's Android desktop.

On websites, Chrome's **Autoplay policy** prevents me from **playing media programatically** if there was no prior user interaction with the website. But this also applies to the PWA. 
Is there a flag for the manifest or some other solution to **allow playback without user gesture** in kiosk mode?

(I don't understand why someone wants to prohibit autoplay of media in a PWA that the user has explicitly installed on the desktop.)

Comment: Autoplaying is generally frowned upon. I would always advice against adding audio autoplay.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes says "Autoplay with sound is allowed if … On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen]." Are you finding this not to be the case?

Comment: @JoshLee interesting... no that's not the case on my device. So is it a bug then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can confirm it has been a bug, which is fixed in Chrome version 76.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977666

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Mohre is quite right, autoplay - or in my case creation of audioContext - is allowed without user-gesture when the PWA is installed.
However, I believe I've discovered a short-fall in Chrome's Trusted Web Activity implementation ...
Since a TWA is a PWA installed from the Play Store, I'd expected the same exemption from the user-gesture rule, but this is not the case.
If you list your PWA in the Play Store - by creating and publishing a TWA - user-gesture is once again required :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29795954)